# Firebase Offline Data

Tags: android, ios, node.js, firebase, web

I have a Firebase collection of users and my user isn't always connected to the network and he needs to access the data from that collection on-demand; is there any other solution other than syncing/downloading the entire collection to the device?

Also, if I have a collection of users that contains 5000 records with just firstname and lastname, both has max of 50 chars - how much disk space do I need to store it? I just want to get an idea how much space it'd take to store those records locally...

Comment: What Firebase database are you using: Firebase Realtime Database (which stores all data into a single JSON tree) or the Cloud Firestore (which stores the data in collections and documents)?

Comment: Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your user isn't connected to the network and needs to be able to access all users, those users will need to be downloaded onto the device before the users loses the connection. I'm not sure I understand what other sort of solution you have in mind.
2. I've never done any such measurement, but I expect it to be small compared to, say your APK size. `5000 * (50+50) = 50kb` Even if the overhead of storing it to disk is `10x` (which is not unreasonable), it would still only be 500kb.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's some magical way to do it other than downloading it. Thanks!